# fill dataframe with different dtype within for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I would like to create a dataframe containing the columns 'start', 'end', 'duration', and 'filename'

```
MyDataframe=pd.DataFrame(columns=['start','end','duration','filename'])
```

The columns start, end and duration should contain integers, and filename strings

I would need to fill the dataframe within a foor loop in which I read a file and I calculate start,end and duration of events.

```
for i in range(0,numFiles):
  [detected_events] = calculateevents(filename)
```

detected_events is an array containing the start,end and duration of all the events in filename

```
detected_events
Out[4]: 
array([[ 24737,  24807,      4],
       [ 36221,  36221,      1],
       [ 37563,  37652,      4],
       ..., 
       [179738, 179738,      1],
       [179829, 179829,      1],
       [179888, 179888,      1]])
```

I would like to include the information containend in detected events in MyDataframe along with the filename from where these events were calculated, but I cannot find a way. could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you need:

```
dfs = []
for i in range(0,numFiles):
  detected_events = calculateevents(filename)
  #create df by numpy array
  MyDataframe = pd.DataFrame(detected_events, columns=['start','end','duration'])
  #add new column, second row fill to filename (another values are NaN)
  MyDataframe[1, 'filename'] = filename
  #add df to list  
  dfs.append(MyDataframe)

#concat all df to one big 
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, but MyDataframe should grow at each iteration... I would like that the second row of the Dataframe contains the events found in the second filename

Comment: In each loop I read a file called filename and I need to add to the dataframe the start/end/duration of the events found in filename together with the filename, in the next iteration I read another file etc..

Comment: It is not a problem..I would need to append the new data to the dataframe

Comment: how do you read files? by [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) ?